# ADDRESS formula INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-2 COLUMN()+2))})) add Text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi There is any way to add text this formula

=IFERROR(DGET(Data,"Qty",{"Name";"=" & INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-24, COLUMN()+2))}))

Results will be **"117"**

I Want add Text **"Total "** So Results will be **"Total 117"**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `"Total " &` to your formula.  Example:

> =IFERROR("Total " & DGET(Data,"Qty",{"Name";"=" & INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-24, COLUMN()+2))}))

Alternatively, if you wish for the numbers to retain their value you can go to Custom Number Format and change the format there.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Type **Total** in the form field and the cell values will be retained.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Codedabbler 2nd questions 

=IFERROR(DGET(Data,"Qty",{"Name";"=" & INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-24, COLUMN()+2))}))

INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-24, COLUMN()+2) this is finding cell is D2 and its value is Apple then DGET will search Apple 

so can we do that cell contain is Apple so it will find D2 "Apple" but I Like to add Text " Total End" So it will find "Apple Total End" and get result 117

Comment: Like from=IFERROR(DGET('Buy&Sell'!$M$3:$U,"COST",{"CODE";"=" & D2})) to
 =IFERROR(DGET('Buy&Sell'!$M$3:$U,"COST",{"CODE";"=" & D2&" Total"}))

Comment: If you have another question, please submit that as a separate question to keep each question focused on one topic.  Feel free to add a link to the new question in the comments here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77141917/dgetdata-qty-name-indirectaddressrow-24-column2-add-text